# How to generate an XML file dynamically using XDocument?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xsd

As I wrote in the subject itself , how can I do that?
Note that solution like this are not appropriate as I want to create child nodes dynamically through running..

```
new XDocument(
    new XElement("root", 
        new XElement("someNode", "someValue")    
    )
)
.Save("foo.xml");
```

**I guess this was clear enough the first time but I will write it again:**

I need to be able to add child nodes to given parent node while running, in the current syntax I've written this is static generated xml which doesn't contribute me at all because all is known in advance, which is not as my case.

How would you do it with Xdocument, is there away?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've tried therfore I'm asking, there are so much xml methods that it making me xonfused: `xmlWriter` `Xpath` `Xdocument` `xmlDocument`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple

Please update your code accordingly

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = xml.CreateElement("children");
xml.AppendChild(root);

XmlComment comment = xml.CreateComment("Children below...");
root.AppendChild(comment);

for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    XmlElement child = xml.CreateElement("child");
    child.SetAttribute("age", i.ToString());
    root.AppendChild(child);
}
string s = xml.OuterXml;
```

Comment: What is dynamic about this?

Comment: new XElement("someNode", "someValue")

As its not known he need to atleast frame out method to implement dynamic value

Comment: That line doesn't even exist in your code. *And* you don't even use XDocument, which is what OP is looking for. I don't think you understand what the word "dynamic" means. Nothing you've put so far is dynamic.

Comment: Agreed, but it can be done like this too.
The values had to be replaced, contents need to be changed.

Comment: Your solution still has **nothing dynamic about it**. It doesn't even accept any input or values. The *entire solution* is static. Replacing string values in that solution STILL is not dynamic.

Comment: @tnw: so what is your solution??

Answer (score 9):

If a document has a defined structure and should be filled with dynamic data, you can go like this:

```
// Setup base structure:
var doc = new XDocument(root);
var root = new XElement("items");
doc.Add(root);

// Retrieve some runtime data:
var data = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

// Generate the rest of the document based on runtime data:
root.Add(data.Select(x => new XElement("item", x)));
```